# Terminal: missing command line, bash in endless loop

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, terminal

Since this morning Terminal has been acting strangely. It runs login and bash (the shell), but the ID keeps running up (it should equal the ID of login and remain constant) and opens additional processes like `sort, cat, env` and then closing them. This prevented me from entering any commands.

In trying to solve the problem I did a `Shell -> Send Reset` and `Shell -> Send Hard Reset`, which didn't solve the problem and now my command line is gone. I can still enter commands via `Shell -> New commands`.

I've created another admin user and tested terminal and that works.

I'm looking to stop the endless loop and restore my command line.

My OS is OSX 10.9.5

Comment: Have you modifed your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` recently?

Comment: Restore your shell startup scripts from Time Machine.

Comment: @thatotherguy Not before this started happening. How do I open those files?

Comment: @thatotherguy I can't find them. Is there a command I can put in terminal to find them?

Comment: They would be in your home directory (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`), but won't show by default in Finder because Finder doesn't show hidden files (those starting with a dot); you need to hit cmd-shift-period to toggle that.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov cmd-shift-period gives an error sound and does not show hidden folders/files